# How do I export a view in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, export, mysql-workbench

I am trying to export a query in MySQL Workbench. I want to export only certain columns, hence I am exporting a query, not an entire table.

My current approach is to create a view comprised of the columns of interest, then export it. MySQL Workbench has wizard for table import/export, but I don't see any functionality for view export. Am I missing something?

I'm not using `INTO OUTFILE` because I'm having file permission issues and I'm not the system admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the `Table Export Wizard` menu entry is only available on a table node in the schema tree. But look closer: the wizard still lists not only tables, but also views:

[image]

I'll take care to have this menu entry added also to views in the schema tree.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in *Data Export* wizard:

[image]

Note that in the above example, I am exporting `actor_info` view.

See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html) for more info.

Comment: thanks for the response. I am using MySQL Workbench 6.3. My MySQL install is 5.something. When I right-click "Views" it does not present me with an export option. Same for when I right-click the name of the view. It's possible to open that "Data Export" screen by hitting "Data Export" in the MANAGEMENT tab (in the upper left of your screenshot). When I export the view that way, it only exports structure, etc but no data. I'm not sure why it's different.

Comment: @sameagol: make sure you have chosen: **Dump Structure and Data** (highlighted in the image). I assume your current setting is: **Dump Structure Only**

Comment: I tried 'Dump Structure and Data' as well as 'Dump Data Only' but it still did not work. Sorry for no screenshot, I can't do it. The other suggestion worked, check it out!